# Adsense for mobile or Adsense for content?

Tags: android, adsense

I have developed an android app which parses the website content and displays them on mobile by mapping the content to android specific `View`. Please note that this app is not the optimized version of website.
I am thinking to monetize it by using `Adsense`.
But, i am little confused on which `Adsense` should I use? Adsense for mobile or Adsense for content, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adsense is for websites, and Adsense for mobile is for mobile optimized websites.

If you are displaying the content using an android UI as opposed to a WebView, you should be using [AdMob](https://www.google.com/admob/).

Keep in mind that almost all ad networks will have a clause in the TOS that you must own the content that you are monetizing. That is, you cannot parse someone else's website and monetize it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Given that it is possible for me to change android UI to WebView, Which is advisable? Using admob or adsense for mobile?

Comment: According to Google: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/68724, you should use AdSense for content since Android is considered a high-end device.

Comment: Adsense for content when I use WebView, right? Means I do not have any option other than Admob when I go with the Android UI opposed to WebView?

Comment: AdMob is Google's solution. You have dozens of other choices if you do not want to use Google.